# Stokes theorem for manifolds with corners

Tags: real-analysis, integration, differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

I wonder if you could recommend a chapter or a paper on Stokes theorem for manifolds with corners.

I've found one here http://math.stanford.edu/~conrad/diffgeomPage/handouts.html (the third one from the bottom).

The statement is:

Let $(M, \mu)$ be an oriented manifold with corners and with constant dimension $n \ge 1$. Choose a compactly supported $\omega \in \Omega_{n-1}(M)$ and give $\partial (M_{\le 1})$ the induuced orientation $\partial \mu$ as the boundary of the manifold-with-boundary $M_{n \le 1}$. Then $\omega$ is absolutely integrable on $\partial (M_{\le 1})$ and $\int_{M} d \omega = \int_{\partial M_{\le 1}} \omega$

But while proving the theorem, the author explains how to prove the theorem above copying the proof of the Stokes theorem for manifolds with boundary and the problem is that I cannot find that proof on his website.

Do you know any other papers or books where (maybe other version of ) the theorem is proved?

Comment: See also Lang's *Real Analysis*. My edition is 1969. In the very last section he treats Stokes's Theorem with singularities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are looking for reference that specifically deals with Stokes' formula on manifolds with corners, John M. Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifold, Second Edition, page 415-419 treats the case.